# Instance as a position argument of another instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have this code:

```
class Location():
    def __init__(self, north, south, east, west):
        self.north = north
        self.south = south
        self.east = east
        self.west = west

ruins = Location(forest1,beach1,forest2,beach2)
forest1 = Location(forest3,ruins,forest4,beach3)
```

Is there a way to use instances as values for positional arguments as above or is there a better way to do this? I keep getting `forest1 not defined` because it's referenced before assignment but to do it this way some will have to be. I believe I have answered myself, this isn't possible so how can I get this kind of setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use a variable before it is declared. What you can do is to allow empty objects to be initialised, and populate attributes later:

```
class Location():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def set_directions(self, north, south, east, west):
        self.north = north
        self.south = south
        self.east = east
        self.west = west

ruins = Location()
forest1 = Location()
# ...
ruins.set_directions(forest1, beach1, forest2, beach2)
forest1.set_directions(forest3, ruins, forest4, beach3)
```